# Include a record by default in any association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Client Model as below:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :custodians,:dependent => :destroy
```

I have a Custodian Model as below:

```
class Custodian < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
```

In my custodians table I have record with id = 0 , name = 'N/A' that I want to include in all my collection_selects irrespective of the client_id.

e.g for client_id = 10 I want the following in collection_select

```
Custodian.where('client_id = 10 or client_id = 0')
```

I know I can do it in my views but I have too many views so it is not practical. Plus I want a more DRY method on either Custodian model or associations. I tried default_scope on Custodian model but could not get it to work.

Basically I am looking for way to always include custodian with id=0 in each association and collection_select.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want using a `has_many` and `belongs_to` approach.  To implement a `belongs_to` relationship, the `Custodian` record has to have a single `client_id` field.  Your logic requires that the `custodian_id=0` record belong to many `Client` records, so it would have to have many `client_id` fields, but it can only have one.  See the Rails Guides-Active Record Associations-The belongs_to Association (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

You can accomplish what you want by using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.  By making both the `Custodian` and `Client` models `has_and_belongs_to_many` to each other, you will be able to have the `custodian_id=0` record belong to many `Client` records and all the other Custodian records will only belong to one client (even though they could belong to many, your program logic must only allow them to belong to one.)  See the `has_and_belongs_to_many` section of the above Rails Guide.  To be clear, here is how your models would look:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :custodians
end

class Custodian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :client
end
```

Also, because of your special case on `custodian_id=0`, you will need to establish the look-up table record for the `custodian_id=0` record relationship using an `active_record` callback (probably `before_validation` or `before_create`) when you create a new `Client` record.

Similarly, you will need to implement your own `:dependent => :destroy` functionality using the `before_destroy` callback to preserve the `custodian_id=0` record and delete all the other associated `Custodian` records.  You'll also have to destroy the corresponding look-up table entries.

This sounds like a lot of work, but if you absolutely must have the `custodian_id=0` record associated with every `Client`, this is the only way I can see it being done.  You may want to evaluate it this is really necessary.  There may be other program logic that could allow you to get to similar results without going through this process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance or class method:

```
#app/models/client.rb
Class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :custodians,:dependent => :destroy

    def inc_zero(id)
        where("client_id = ? OR client_id = 0", id)
    end

    def self.inc_zero_custodians(id)
        joins(:custodians).where("client_id = ? OR client_id = 0", id)
    end
end

#-> Client.custodians.inc_zero(10)
#-> Client.inc_zero_custodians(10)
```

Comment: Rich, tried your method                                 :irb(main):006:0* Client.custodians.inc_zero(1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `custodians' for #<Class:0x87d28d0>
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:1009:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):6
irb(main):007:0> Client.find(1).custodians.count
=> 65
irb(main):008:0> Client.inc_zero_custodians(1).count
=> 65
irb(main):009:0>  last statement should give 66 custodians

Comment: Your first test failed because you can't call `custodians` on a non-initialized class. `custodians` can only be a method of an already-initialized class: `class = Class.find(1)` `class.custodians.inc_zero(1)`

Comment: For second, it's good that it's returning data -- can you give us the SQL query it generated?